# Longtable with specific columnwidth

Tags: longtable, columns, width

I have been trying to resolve this for days and now I surrender. 
I need a table that can span multiple pages, so I started using longtable instead of tabularx. I tried to do a fixed width column (the first one) but I still get it too wide. when I try to shrink it to 3 or 4cm, it doesn't work.

```
\section{Main structural statistical parameters for the conformers calculated}
\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTleft{-2cm}
\setlength\LTright{-4cm}
     \begin{longtable}{r{4cm} |c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption[Chemical shift list of PG-T4 in \ce{H2O}, pH 3.5] {Main structural statistical parameters for the ensemble of the 20 lowest target function conformers calculated for PG-T4, PG-C6C15, PG-C8C13 in \ce{H2O} and 30 mM DPC, pH 3.5}\\
\toprule
 &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{\ce{H2O}}}   &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{30 mM DPC}}   \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
          & 
        \textbf{PG-T4} & 
        \textbf{PG-C6C15} & 
        \textbf{PG-C8C13} & 
        \textbf{PG-T4} & 
        \textbf{PG-C6C15} & 
        \textbf{PG-C8C13} 
\\

\endfirsthead
\toprule
         & &
        \textbf{PG-T4}  & 
        \textbf{PG-C6C15}  & 
        \textbf{PG-C8C13}& 
        \textbf{PG-T4}  & 
        \textbf{PG-C6C15}  & 
        \textbf{PG-C8C13}
        \\
\midrule
\endhead
\endhead
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape continue on the next page} % <-- added
\endfoot
\endlastfoot

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Upper Limit distance restraints (from NOEs)             &       &       &       &       &       &       \\  
        \tab Total  &   numbers &   numbers &   numbers &   numbers &   numbers &   numbers \\  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage
```

If you can help me to find what's happening here, I would be very thankful.

[image]

I tried your solutions, @koleygr and this is the result:
[image: new solution]

Comment: A first comment (that may solve your problem) is that I see 7 columns in the output but you use only 6 when defining the table... This is possibly that causes the problem

Comment: `r{4cm}` doesn't exist. probably you looking for `>{\raggedleft\arraybacslash}p{4cm}`. for numbers are advisable use`S` columns from `siunitx` package ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `ltablex`, which is combination of `longtable` and `tabularx`, you can write long table in `tabularx` format.

an example (based on mwe in [koleygr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/120578/koleygr) answer) anticipated that "numbers" will ones be real numbers, for which i suggest to use `S` column type from `siunitx` package, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, ltablex, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X *{6}{S[table-format=2.3]}}
\caption[Chemical shift list of PG-T4 in \ce{H2O}, pH 3.5]
        {Main structural statistical parameters for the ensemble of the 20 lowest target function conformers calculated for PG-T4, PG-C6C15, PG-C8C13 in \ce{H2O} and 30 mM DPC, pH 3.5}
\label{tab:long-table}  \\
    \toprule
    &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{\ce{H2O}}}    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{30 mM DPC}}   \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
        & {\thead{PG-T4}}   & {\thead{PG-C6C15}}    & {\thead{PG-C8C13}}
        & {\thead{PG-T4}}   & {\thead{PG-C6C15}}    & {\thead{PG-C8C13}}            \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Main structural statistical parameters for the ensemble of the 20 lowest target function conformers calculated for PG-T4, PG-C6C15, PG-C8C13 in \ce{H2O} and 30 mM DPC, pH 3.5 (cont.)}\\
    \toprule
    &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{\ce{H2O}}}    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{30 mM DPC}}   \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
        & {\thead{PG-T4}}   & {\thead{PG-C6C15}}    & {\thead{PG-C8C13}}
        & {\thead{PG-T4}}   & {\thead{PG-C6C15}}    & {\thead{PG-C8C13}}            \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape continue on the next page}                 \\
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Upper Limit distance restraints (from NOEs)
        &           &           &           &           &           &               \\
Total   & 12.345    & 22.345    & 32.345    & 42.345    & 52.345    & 62.345        \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

after three times compilation you will obtain:

[image]

Comment: @DNA... it would be nice from you to accept the right answer... (It is a good practice in the forums we use not to let posts to be unanswered)

Comment: @koleygr sorry I haven't answered until now, I had a medical emergency.

Comment: I have a problem, It's not working at all, what I get after several compilations is the first column invading all

Comment: "not working" is not helpful. what do you doing? image of table showed in answer is generated with proposed code. so the code is tested and for sure it works.

Comment: I'm sorry I have been a mess, I finally found out how to upload an image I get when I compile three times the code. Thank you for you help.

Comment: i'm glad to hear that you managed your (unexpected) problem. then now is time to accept one of received answer ... :-)

Comment: What I meant is that I still get the first column overwriting the rest of the columns, https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEHet.png

Comment: see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but nothing is working, having the same result and here https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEHet.png even compyling 5 times, I put all the packages in the preamble, everything. I give up, for sure, you are right.

Comment: if you compile my answer as it is, you should work. if not work in your document, than you have confusion in your document preamble or even in document.  the best remedy is rewrite it from scratch and care that each package is loaded only ones, that all your definitions are not in conflict etc.

Comment: I will do it, recompile from scratch. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

1) There was 2 problems in the parameters of  columntypes that will be used

First: less columns (6 instead of 7)

Second: r column doesn't take argument of length (except if you redefined it first)  I used p columntype that takes argument and breaks the lines automatically (You may try m instead or `>{\arraybackslash\raggedleft}p{4cm}` if you really need it aligned right)

2) There was an extra separator in last line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\def\tab{}
\begin{document}
\section{Main structural statistical parameters for the conformers calculated}
\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTleft{-2cm}
\setlength\LTright{-4cm}
     \begin{longtable}{p{4cm} cccccc}
\caption[Chemical shift list of PG-T4 in \ce{H2O}, pH 3.5] {Main structural statistical parameters for the ensemble of the 20 lowest target function conformers calculated for PG-T4, PG-C6C15, PG-C8C13 in \ce{H2O} and 30 mM DPC, pH 3.5}\\
\toprule
 &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{\ce{H2O}}}   &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{30 mM DPC}}   \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
          & 
        \textbf{PG-T4} & 
        \textbf{PG-C6C15} & 
        \textbf{PG-C8C13} & 
        \textbf{PG-T4} & 
        \textbf{PG-C6C15} & 
        \textbf{PG-C8C13} 
\\

\endfirsthead
\toprule
         & 
        \textbf{PG-T4}  & 
        \textbf{PG-C6C15}  & 
        \textbf{PG-C8C13}& 
        \textbf{PG-T4}  & 
        \textbf{PG-C6C15}  & 
        \textbf{PG-C8C13}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\endhead
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape continue on the next page} % <-- added
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Upper Limit distance restraints (from NOEs)             &       &       &       &       &       &       \\  
        \tab Total  &   numbers &   numbers &   numbers &   numbers &   numbers &   numbers \\  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my mistake I didn't put my preamble in which I put what "tab" really means.

Comment: Welcome... removing the bold :P (just wanted to see it)

Comment: Not working, but thank you. I'll keep trying.